# TypeScript doesn't recognize an object in Request response from supertest?

Tags: typescript, supertest

I'm writing a test for a *very* simple graphql API in TypeScript using Supertest. I'm getting this error: `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Response'`, and why should it? I haven't told it what to expect there. But how can I? **data** is immediately followed by **should**.

[image]

Here is my short test file.

```
import chai from "chai";
import { expect } from "chai";
import * as request from "supertest";
import app from "../src";

describe("graphQl test", () => {

    it("should respond with hello world", async (done) => {

        const returned = await request(app)
            .post("/graphql")
            .send({ query: "{ hello }"})
            .expect(200)
            .end((err, res) => {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                res.data.should.have.property("hello");
                done();
            });

        expect(returned.data.hello).equal("Hello world!");
    });
});
```

Is there a simple solution to this? If not, I'm imagining I have to create some kind of interface, but how would I create an interface and communicate that interface to TypeScript in this scenario? I'm searching but I have yet to see an example of this.

Comment: returned can also be error `return done(err);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had all of my typings installed. In this case, I think the problem became solved in the process of getting Mocha to work with `ts-node`. `ts-node` didn't work with my global `typescript` so I had to install that locally. Then I needed to add a separate `tsconfig.json` file for my tests and VSCode stopped giving me those errors and compilation worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to add supertest types so the compiler will know what to expect.

it can be done like this:

```
npm install --save @types/supertest
```